# Really close lines with NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I want to have two lines of text appear really close together (small line spacing) for a button. I have the following code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"50 WPM"];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrapStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragrapStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
paragrapStyle.lineSpacing = -10;

[string addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrapStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

UIFont *font1 = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font1 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length - 4)];

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(string.length - 3, 3)];

[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

[self.button setAttributedTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But as linespacing can't be negative, it doesn't get nearly as close as I'd like it to be. It looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to get them closer?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the paragraph style's `paragraphSpacing` and `paragraphSpacingBefore` properties?

Comment: I tried under `paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = -10;` to set those attributes on `paragrapStyle` to 0 (as well as -10 afterword) and neither had any noticeable effect.

Comment: @DougSmith you use negative value for line spacing as per apple doc. Try something like (0.0000001).

Answer (score 57):

Well if you have an attribute string then everything should be possible. :) You just have to look more.

```
- (void)setMinimumLineHeight:(CGFloat)aFloat
- (void)setMaximumLineHeight:(CGFloat)aFloat
```

Try

```
[paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:0.0f];
[paragraphStyle setMaximumLineHeight:7.0f];
```

You will realise that maximumLineHeight is not maximumLineSpacing. ^^

**This for example is with setMaximumLineHeight:12];**

[image]

Comment: My issue there is that text gets cut off.

Comment: What if you turn off `masksToBounds` or add a baseline adjustment or translation transform?

Answer (score 3):

Here a little extension in Swift3 which supports negative lineSpacing

```
extension UILabel {
    func set(lineSpacing: CGFloat, textAlignment: NSTextAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center) {
        if let text = self.text {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            if lineSpacing < 0 {
                paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0
                paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = self.font.pointSize + lineSpacing
            } else {
                paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
            }
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            self.attributedText = attrString
            self.textAlignment = textAlignment
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading up on [TextKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html) that was introduced in iOS7. I do not have much experience from it, but I do know that it gives you a lot of possibilities when it comes to attributing your texts.

Comment: There's a real lack of TextKit tutorials for something simple like this unfortunately. I feel lost in a sea of complexity.

Comment: This is unfortunately true. Ray Wenderlich does awesome tutorials, perhaps you could try out his! http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, you can achieve this by :

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.lineSpacing = 0
paragraph.maximumLineHeight = 20.
```

Keep the lineSpacing = 0. You can adjust the maximumLineHeight to make it closer or to increase the spacing.

Answer (score -2):

How about subclassing `UIButton`, and add 2 `UILabels` to the buttons view that are close together. Create properties for the labels and set approrpietly:

```
CustomButton *btn = [CustomButton new];

btn.textLine1 = @"Top";
btn.textLine2 = @"Bottom";
```

The only problem doing it this way is you will need to handle the text color when the state changes yourself.